# Does two same light bulbs produce light of same frequency?

Tags: optics, visible-light, frequency, interference, superposition

If they do, then why don't we observe interference in normal rooms? And if they don't have the same frequency then why is that so?

Comment: I don't really know, and I'm interested in an answer to your question myself. What I know is that light bulbs don't emit on one single frequency, but on a spectrum of frequencies. And then, they are not lasers putting out the photons in one single beam, but in short, random pulses in random directions, so what you expect as interference does not occur on an observable scale.

Comment: @GyroGearloose that's pretty much the answer that they are incoherent polychromatic sources, you could attempt to word that as an answer. There might also be additional considerations in that no light bulb is actually identical to the next.

Comment: I upvoted this question, but now I see it is in zero state. So someone has been down-voting.  I won't burn my hands on answering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does light in a room not form constructive and destructive interference patterns?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15809/)

Answer (score 3):

Ordinary light bulbs emit photons of light with a wide range of frequencies and with random phases. To observe interference patterns you need either (a) a very small difference in path lengths (e.g. interference between light reflected from the two surfaces of a thin film of oil) or (b) a light source that produces [coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics)) light with a single frequency (or as near to that as possible). The latter is usually achieved with a laser.

Comment: But we can see interference with sunlight ... for example on a puddle with oil!  And of course Thomas Young used sunlight for his famous interference experiment.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Good point. I have updated my answer.